# React: Access to the (updated) state with useState: it is not updated inside the component that creates it, but it is outside where it is called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state, use-state

Why am I not having access to the updated `recipes` (`useState`) value from inside the component that defines it?

In this example you can see how not being able to access to this value causes an error in the app once the reference to a function that I use to update the state is deleted

=> Codebox and code below

*Click two times the `<h1>` to see the error

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-sea-5iqgo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userRecipes, setUserRecipes] = useRecipesData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1
        onClick={() => {
          userRecipes.setBookmarks("onetwothree");
        }}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </h1>
      <h2>{userRecipes.bookmarked_recipes}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const useRecipesData = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState({});

  const setBookmarks = newRecipes => {
    console.log(recipes); // is undefined !? and deletes setBookmarks
    setRecipes({
      bookmarked_recipes: newRecipes,
      setBookmarks: recipes.setBookmarks
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setRecipes({
      bookmarked_recipes: "testtesttest",
      setBookmarks: setBookmarks
    });
  }, []);

  return [recipes, setRecipes];
};
```

What I don't understand is why if I return `[recipes, setRecipes]` where `recipes.setBookmarks` stores a reference to a function, it doesn't work

But if I return the function itself (which is a reference as well) `[recipes, setBookmarks]` then it works

See this other codebox where it does work

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-violet-gju99?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [userRecipes, setUserRecipes] = useRecipesData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1
        onClick={() => {
          setUserRecipes("onetwothree" + Math.random());
        }}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </h1>
      <h2>{userRecipes.bookmarked_recipes}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const useRecipesData = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState({});

  const setBookmarks = newRecipes => {
    console.log(recipes); // is defined this time
    setRecipes({
      bookmarked_recipes: newRecipes,
      setBookmarks: recipes.setBookmarks
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setRecipes({
      bookmarked_recipes: "testtesttest",
      setBookmarks: setBookmarks
    });
  }, []);

  return [recipes, setBookmarks];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about context.
If you'll put `console.log(receipes)` in useEffect and the render function itself, you can see what the flow of events are:

1. First render recipe is empty.
2. UseEffect is called and puts setBookmark in recipe (but the recipe for setBookmark is empty)
3. Second render is called, and now recipe has "testesttest" and `recipe.setBookmark` is a function where the recipe object that is bound to it is the recipe value from event 1
4. setBookmark is called, recipe is now set to "onetwothree" but the recipe object is empty so we set the setBookmark to undefined.

instead of keeping the function inside the state, you need to just call it directly (I.E. return setBookmark and not setRecipes, like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [userRecipes, setBookmarks] = useRecipesData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1
        onClick={() => {
          setBookmarks("onetwothree" + Math.random());
        }}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </h1>
      <h2>{userRecipes.bookmarked_recipes}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const useRecipesData = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState({});
  const setBookmarks = newRecipes => {
    setRecipes({
      bookmarked_recipes: newRecipes,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setRecipes({
      bookmarked_recipes: "testtesttest",
    });
  }, []);

  return [recipes, setBookmarks];
};
```

Comment: What I don't get is why returning `setBookmark` (a ref), the `console.log(recipes)` works, but returning the same function in a variable (because it is also a ref), the `console.log(recipes)` gets the non-updated `recipes` (I'm rewriting the question to show you the code I'm talking about)